# coreos : curl http://matchbox.example.com:8080 connection refused

Tags: http, openshift, coreos, ipxe

I am trying to boot using ipxe and for that I am using matchbox from CoreOS. Normally http://matchbox.example.com:8080 should return "Matchbox" but for me it is giving "Connection refused" . I can dig and ping matchbox.example.com. The firewalld service is not running.

Comment: Try https://matchbox.example.com. What do you get when you run ```oc get route --all-namespaces```

Comment: Thanks. The matchbox service had failed to start. The problem got solved by just running the command below and restarting the service.

[root@matchbox]# chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/matchbox